# How to insert Null and empty string in database using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a model that accepts code as NULL, empty and any other string value along with an `IsCodeNull` `bool` property

```
public class Translation : IEquatable<Translation>
{
    private string code;
    private bool isCodeNull;

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Code
    {
        get
        {
            if (code == null)
                isCodeNull = true;
            else
                isCodeNull = false;
            return code;
        }
        set
        {
            code = value;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsCodeNull
    {
        get { return isCodeNull; }
        set { isCodeNull = value; }
    }
}
```

---View----

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsCodeNull) (check this box, If value is NULL)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
</div>
```

How can I store null values in the database when the checkbox is true, and store string.empty when it is false.

I can't use the `dbNull.Value`: it's giving me an error that it cannot explicitly convert from `null` to `string`.

Comment: Can you just add the logic to your controller?  There you can check if IsCodeNull is true or false and then set Code accordingly before calling SaveChanges. This would be instead of trying to do it in the Translation class.

Comment: Does your database allow null values for that field? Is it appropriate to even have a field listed as 'Null'? Wouldn't it be better to have a field named `is_null` that stores `true` or `false`? `NULL` in a database table usually means the database *doesn't know*. In this case you *do* know, but are trying to use the null value to represent that knowledge, which is bad practice.

Comment: I agree with @NathanielFord here. Persist your `IsCodeNull` boolean and then use that to determine where you should respect the value of `Code` or not. Don't use the `Code` property's inherent value of null or not as an indication.

Comment: Yep checkboxes is bool,   or 1/0   on on/off     never null/notnull

Comment: IsCodeNull is not mapped property. so this won't be in table, and Yes, Code  column does allow null.